# Change Protocol from UDP to TCP in a simple chat application

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, udp

I want to change the Protocol i'm using for a simple chat application from using a UDP to use a TCP Protocol.

I declared these objects :

```
Socket sck;
EndPoint epLocal, epRemote;
```

and Initialized them in the Constructor with :

```
sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
```

I have this in the button that starts the Connection :

```
private void btn_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    epLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textLocalIp.Text),Convert.ToInt32(textLocalPort.Text));
    sck.Bind(epLocal);

    epRemote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textFriendsIp.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textFriendsPort.Text));
    sck.Connect(epRemote);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
    sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);
}
```

and in the Sending the Message button click :

```
private void btn_Send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] msg = new byte[1500];
    msg = enc.GetBytes(textMessage.Text);
    sck.Send(msg);
}
```

and here is the "CallBack" Method :

```
private void MessageCallBack(IAsyncResult aResult){
    int size = sck.EndReceiveFrom(aResult, ref epRemote);
    if (size > 0){
        byte[] recievedData = new byte[1464];
        recievedData = (byte[])aResult.AsyncState;
        ASCIIEncoding eEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string recievedMessage = eEncoding.GetString(recievedData);
        listMessage.Items.Add("Friend: "+recievedMessage);
    }
    byte [] buffer = new byte[1500];
    sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);
}
```

so what should i change to get it from using a UDP Protocol to use a TCP Protocol.
Thanks!

Comment: Any reason you can't just use `ProtocolType.Tcp`   and  `SocketType.Stream` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.protocoltype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: yeah I tried that and didn't work,
says: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by it's access permissions

Comment: what port are you using ?

Comment: Client1 "80" and Client2 "81"

Comment: Use a different set of ports.  ( netstat -at )  run that command to help figure out whats open.

Comment: @Nix, tried many different set of open ports, I still have the same exception, What possibly could it be?

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you can't just use [ProtocolType.Tcp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.protocoltype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

```
sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,  
    SocketType.Stream, 
    ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

and blog to help you

http://netrsc.blogspot.com/2010/05/using-asynchronous-sockets.html